# Rational/Irrational Piecewise Function Limit

Tags: calculus, limits, piecewise-continuity

[The question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HN9No.png)

\begin{align} f(x) =
\begin{cases} 
x^2,  & \text{if $n$ is rational} \\
-x^2, & \text{if $n$ is irrational}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
a) \ \text{There is no $a$ where} \lim_{x \to a} f(x) \text{ exists}
\\
b) \ \lim_{x \to a} f(x) \text{ exists only when $a = 0$}
\\
c) \ \lim_{x \to a} f(x) \text{ exists for infinitely many $a$}
\\
d) \ \text{Impossible to answer without more information}
\end{equation}

I originally thought that the answer would be (a) here because there would be no continuity in this function whatsoever as x constantly switches between rational and irrational values, but I am unsure of how I could mathematically explain it. (I have not been taught the epsilon-delta definition, but I do know the squeeze theorem if that could somehow apply here)

Comment: Using $\epsilon -\delta$ approach, you will have continuity at $a=0$.  Therefore (b).

Comment: @herbsteinberg Interesting, would the $\epsilon - \delta$ approach be the only way to solve this?

Comment: $|f(x)| \le x^2$ so it must be continuous at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $-x^2\le f(x) \le x^2$, and $\underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\lim}x^2 = \underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\lim}-x^2 = 0$, by the squeeze theorem, you have $\underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\lim}f(x) = 0$. For any other $a$, you can always find a sequence of rational numbers $a_n$ and a sequence of irrational numbers $b_n$, such that $\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}a_n = \underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}b_n = a$, but then $\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}f(a_n) = \underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim} a_n^2 = a$, $\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}f(b_n) = \underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim} -b_n^2 = -a$. They are not equal since $a\not=0$, so the limit $\underset{x\rightarrow a}{\lim}f(x)$ does not exist. Thus the answer is b).

Comment: I understand the squeeze theorem part and why it would be continuous at 0, as well as the explanation in the second half, I just don't get what you mean by a sequence of numbers. Is there any example you could give using numbers of sequences of rational and irrational numbers?

Comment: The rational sequence is easier to give, for example, when $a = \sqrt{2}$, you can use $a_1 = 1, a_2 = 1.4, a_3 = 1.41, a_4 = 1.414, \ldots$.

Comment: Did you mean ‘the irrational sequence is easier to give’? If so this make perfect sense to me now, thanks.

Comment: The irrational sequence is slightly trickier. You can use the fact that the irrational numbers are dense on the real line (which means that there is at least one irrational number on any interval $(a, b)$)